# Ubuntu 14 - nouveau error

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I use ubuntu 14. About three days ago computer started hanging when I work - I even can't move mouse, so I press power button to restart the computer. It happens about 1-7 times an hour. For example I work in open office and it hangs. Or I work with console - it hangs.

The log is below. What does it mean and how to fix it?

```
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.292875] nouveau E[     PFB][0000:01:00.0] trapped read at 0x002093a000 on channel 0x0000f94c [compiz[2135]] PGRAPH/VFETCH/00 reason: DMAOBJ_LIMIT
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.292908] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] TRAP_VFETCH FAULT
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.292929] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] TRAP_VFETCH 00f00000 0000fe0c 00000000 00000000
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.292938] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] ch 4 [0x000f94c000 compiz[2135]] subc 3 class 0x8297 mthd 0x0f04 data 0x3f800000
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.293036] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] TRAP_VFETCH FAULT
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.293048] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] TRAP_VFETCH 00f00000 0000fe0c 00000000 00000000
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.293057] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] ch 4 [0x000f94c000 compiz[2135]] subc 3 class 0x8297 mthd 0x1b0c data 0x1000f010
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.293071] nouveau E[     PFB][0000:01:00.0] trapped read at 0x00204b6380 on channel 0x0000f94c [compiz[2135]] PGRAPH/VFETCH/00 reason: DMAOBJ_LIMIT
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.304073] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] TRAP_VFETCH FAULT
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.304093] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] TRAP_VFETCH 00f00000 0000fe0c 00000000 00000000
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.304105] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] ch 4 [0x000f94c000 compiz[2135]] subc 3 class 0x8297 mthd 0x15e0 data 0x00000000
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.304120] nouveau E[     PFB][0000:01:00.0] trapped read at 0x002093a000 on channel 0x0000f94c [compiz[2135]] PGRAPH/VFETCH/00 reason: DMAOBJ_LIMIT
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.304156] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] TRAP_VFETCH FAULT
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.304187] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] TRAP_VFETCH 00f00000 0000fe0c 00000000 00000000
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.304202] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] ch 4 [0x000f94c000 compiz[2135]] subc 3 class 0x8297 mthd 0x0dc8 data 0x00000000
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.304376] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] TRAP_VFETCH FAULT
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.304388] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] TRAP_VFETCH 00f00000 0000fe0c 00000000 00000000
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.304397] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] ch 4 [0x000f94c000 compiz[2135]] subc 3 class 0x8297 mthd 0x1b0c data 0x1000f010
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.304411] nouveau E[     PFB][0000:01:00.0] trapped read at 0x00204b6180 on channel 0x0000f94c [compiz[2135]] PGRAPH/VFETCH/00 reason: DMAOBJ_LIMIT
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.329457] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] TRAP_VFETCH FAULT
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.329477] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] TRAP_VFETCH 00f00000 0000fe0c 00000000 00000000
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.329488] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] ch 4 [0x000f94c000 compiz[2135]] subc 3 class 0x8297 mthd 0x15e0 data 0x00000000
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.329504] nouveau E[     PFB][0000:01:00.0] trapped read at 0x002093a000 on channel 0x0000f94c [compiz[2135]] PGRAPH/VFETCH/00 reason: DMAOBJ_LIMIT
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.329541] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] TRAP_VFETCH FAULT
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.329566] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] TRAP_VFETCH 00f00000 0000fe0c 00000000 00000000
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.329575] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] ch 4 [0x000f94c000 compiz[2135]] subc 3 class 0x8297 mthd 0x0dc8 data 0x00000000
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.329737] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] TRAP_VFETCH FAULT
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.329750] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] TRAP_VFETCH 00f00000 0000fe0c 00000000 00000000
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.329758] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] ch 4 [0x000f94c000 compiz[2135]] subc 3 class 0x8297 mthd 0x1b0c data 0x1000f010
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.329772] nouveau E[     PFB][0000:01:00.0] trapped read at 0x00204b6380 on channel 0x0000f94c [compiz[2135]] PGRAPH/VFETCH/00 reason: DMAOBJ_LIMIT
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.338336] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] TRAP_VFETCH FAULT
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.338357] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] TRAP_VFETCH 00f00000 0000fe0c 00000000 00000000
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.338368] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] ch 4 [0x000f94c000 compiz[2135]] subc 3 class 0x8297 mthd 0x15e0 data 0x00000000
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.338384] nouveau E[     PFB][0000:01:00.0] trapped read at 0x002093a000 on channel 0x0000f94c [compiz[2135]] PGRAPH/VFETCH/00 reason: DMAOBJ_LIMIT
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.338415] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] TRAP_VFETCH FAULT
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.338443] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] TRAP_VFETCH 00f00000 0000fe0c 00000000 00000000
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.338452] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] ch 4 [0x000f94c000 compiz[2135]] subc 3 class 0x8297 mthd 0x0dc8 data 0x00000000
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.338618] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] TRAP_VFETCH FAULT
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.338630] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] TRAP_VFETCH 00f00000 0000fe0c 00000000 00000000
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.338639] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] ch 4 [0x000f94c000 compiz[2135]] subc 3 class 0x8297 mthd 0x1b0c data 0x1000f010
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.338654] nouveau E[     PFB][0000:01:00.0] trapped read at 0x00204b6180 on channel 0x0000f94c [compiz[2135]] PGRAPH/VFETCH/00 reason: DMAOBJ_LIMIT
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.354981] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] TRAP_VFETCH FAULT
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.355001] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] TRAP_VFETCH 00f00000 0000fe0c 00000000 00000000
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.355013] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] ch 4 [0x000f94c000 compiz[2135]] subc 3 class 0x8297 mthd 0x15e0 data 0x00000000
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.355031] nouveau E[     PFB][0000:01:00.0] trapped read at 0x002093a000 on channel 0x0000f94c [compiz[2135]] PGRAPH/VFETCH/00 reason: DMAOBJ_LIMIT
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.355061] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] TRAP_VFETCH FAULT
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.355085] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] TRAP_VFETCH 00f00000 0000fe0c 00000000 00000000
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.355097] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] ch 4 [0x000f94c000 compiz[2135]] subc 3 class 0x8297 mthd 0x0f04 data 0x3f800000
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.355195] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] TRAP_VFETCH FAULT
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.355206] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] TRAP_VFETCH 00f00000 0000fe0c 00000000 00000000
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.355214] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] ch 4 [0x000f94c000 compiz[2135]] subc 3 class 0x8297 mthd 0x1b0c data 0x1000f010
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.355229] nouveau E[     PFB][0000:01:00.0] trapped read at 0x00204b6380 on channel 0x0000f94c [compiz[2135]] PGRAPH/VFETCH/00 reason: DMAOBJ_LIMIT
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.371365] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] TRAP_VFETCH FAULT
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.371386] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] TRAP_VFETCH 00f00000 0000fe0c 00000000 00000000
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.371397] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] ch 4 [0x000f94c000 compiz[2135]] subc 3 class 0x8297 mthd 0x15e0 data 0x00000000
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.371413] nouveau E[     PFB][0000:01:00.0] trapped read at 0x002093a000 on channel 0x0000f94c [compiz[2135]] PGRAPH/VFETCH/00 reason: DMAOBJ_LIMIT
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.371440] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] TRAP_VFETCH FAULT
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.371459] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] TRAP_VFETCH 00f00000 0000fe0c 00000000 00000000
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.371465] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] ch 4 [0x000f94c000 compiz[2135]] subc 3 class 0x8297 mthd 0x0dc8 data 0x00000000
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.371624] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] TRAP_VFETCH FAULT
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.371636] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] TRAP_VFETCH 00f00000 0000fe0c 00000000 00000000
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.371645] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] ch 4 [0x000f94c000 compiz[2135]] subc 3 class 0x8297 mthd 0x1b0c data 0x1000f010
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.371659] nouveau E[     PFB][0000:01:00.0] trapped read at 0x00204b6180 on channel 0x0000f94c [compiz[2135]] PGRAPH/VFETCH/00 reason: DMAOBJ_LIMIT
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.387885] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] TRAP_VFETCH FAULT
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.387905] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] TRAP_VFETCH 00f00000 0000fe0c 00000000 00000000
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.387916] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] ch 4 [0x000f94c000 compiz[2135]] subc 3 class 0x8297 mthd 0x15e0 data 0x00000000
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.387931] nouveau E[     PFB][0000:01:00.0] trapped read at 0x002093a000 on channel 0x0000f94c [compiz[2135]] PGRAPH/VFETCH/00 reason: DMAOBJ_LIMIT
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.387952] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] TRAP_VFETCH FAULT
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.387962] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] TRAP_VFETCH 00f00000 0000fe0c 00000000 00000000
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.387970] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] ch 4 [0x000f94c000 compiz[2135]] subc 3 class 0x8297 mthd 0x0dc8 data 0x00000000
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.388133] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] TRAP_VFETCH FAULT
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.388145] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] TRAP_VFETCH 00f00000 0000fe0c 00000000 00000000
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.388153] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] ch 4 [0x000f94c000 compiz[2135]] subc 3 class 0x8297 mthd 0x1b0c data 0x1000f010
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.388168] nouveau E[     PFB][0000:01:00.0] trapped read at 0x00204b6380 on channel 0x0000f94c [compiz[2135]] PGRAPH/VFETCH/00 reason: DMAOBJ_LIMIT
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.405478] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] TRAP_VFETCH FAULT
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.405500] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] TRAP_VFETCH 00f00000 0000fe0c 00000000 00000000
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.405514] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] ch 4 [0x000f94c000 compiz[2135]] subc 3 class 0x8297 mthd 0x15e0 data 0x00000000
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.405532] nouveau E[     PFB][0000:01:00.0] trapped read at 0x002093a000 on channel 0x0000f94c [compiz[2135]] PGRAPH/VFETCH/00 reason: DMAOBJ_LIMIT
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.405554] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] TRAP_VFETCH FAULT
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.405565] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] TRAP_VFETCH 00f00000 0000fe0c 00000000 00000000
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.405573] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] ch 4 [0x000f94c000 compiz[2135]] subc 3 class 0x8297 mthd 0x0dc8 data 0x00000000
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.405733] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] TRAP_VFETCH FAULT
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.405745] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] TRAP_VFETCH 00f00000 0000fe0c 00000000 00000000
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.405753] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] ch 4 [0x000f94c000 compiz[2135]] subc 3 class 0x8297 mthd 0x1b0c data 0x1000f010
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.405767] nouveau E[     PFB][0000:01:00.0] trapped read at 0x00204b6180 on channel 0x0000f94c [compiz[2135]] PGRAPH/VFETCH/00 reason: DMAOBJ_LIMIT
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.424274] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] TRAP_VFETCH FAULT
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.424290] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] TRAP_VFETCH 00f00000 0000fe0c 00000000 00000000
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.424299] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] ch 4 [0x000f94c000 compiz[2135]] subc 3 class 0x8297 mthd 0x15e0 data 0x00000000
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.424313] nouveau E[     PFB][0000:01:00.0] trapped read at 0x002093a000 on channel 0x0000f94c [compiz[2135]] PGRAPH/VFETCH/00 reason: DMAOBJ_LIMIT
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.424449] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] TRAP_VFETCH FAULT
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.424459] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] TRAP_VFETCH 00f00000 0000fe0c 00000000 00000000
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.424464] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] ch 4 [0x000f94c000 compiz[2135]] subc 3 class 0x8297 mthd 0x1b0c data 0x1000f010
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.424475] nouveau E[     PFB][0000:01:00.0] trapped read at 0x00204b6380 on channel 0x0000f94c [compiz[2135]] PGRAPH/VFETCH/00 reason: DMAOBJ_LIMIT
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.437337] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] TRAP_VFETCH FAULT
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.437351] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] TRAP_VFETCH 00f00000 0000fe0c 00000000 00000000
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.437360] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] ch 4 [0x000f94c000 compiz[2135]] subc 3 class 0x8297 mthd 0x15e0 data 0x00000000
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.437373] nouveau E[     PFB][0000:01:00.0] trapped read at 0x002093a000 on channel 0x0000f94c [compiz[2135]] PGRAPH/VFETCH/00 reason: DMAOBJ_LIMIT
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.437388] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] TRAP_VFETCH FAULT
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.437396] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] TRAP_VFETCH 00f00000 0000fe0c 00000000 00000000
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.437401] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] ch 4 [0x000f94c000 compiz[2135]] subc 3 class 0x8297 mthd 0x0dc8 data 0x00000000
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.437561] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] TRAP_VFETCH FAULT
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.437569] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] TRAP_VFETCH 00f00000 0000fe0c 00000000 00000000
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.437575] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] ch 4 [0x000f94c000 compiz[2135]] subc 3 class 0x8297 mthd 0x1b0c data 0x1000f010
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.437586] nouveau E[     PFB][0000:01:00.0] trapped read at 0x00204b6180 on channel 0x0000f94c [compiz[2135]] PGRAPH/VFETCH/00 reason: DMAOBJ_LIMIT
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.458990] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] TRAP_VFETCH FAULT
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.459003] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] TRAP_VFETCH 00f00000 0000fe0c 00000000 00000000
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.459008] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] ch 4 [0x000f94c000 compiz[2135]] subc 3 class 0x8297 mthd 0x15e0 data 0x00000000
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.459019] nouveau E[     PFB][0000:01:00.0] trapped read at 0x002093a000 on channel 0x0000f94c [compiz[2135]] PGRAPH/VFETCH/00 reason: DMAOBJ_LIMIT
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.459041] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] TRAP_VFETCH FAULT
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.459067] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] TRAP_VFETCH 00f00000 0000fe0c 00000000 00000000
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.459072] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] ch 4 [0x000f94c000 compiz[2135]] subc 3 class 0x8297 mthd 0x0dc8 data 0x00000000
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.459232] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] TRAP_VFETCH FAULT
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.459239] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] TRAP_VFETCH 00f00000 0000fe0c 00000000 00000000
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.459242] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] ch 4 [0x000f94c000 compiz[2135]] subc 3 class 0x8297 mthd 0x1b0c data 0x1000f010
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.459252] nouveau E[     PFB][0000:01:00.0] trapped read at 0x00204b6380 on channel 0x0000f94c [compiz[2135]] PGRAPH/VFETCH/00 reason: DMAOBJ_LIMIT
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.471067] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] TRAP_VFETCH FAULT
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.471088] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] TRAP_VFETCH 00f00000 0000fe0c 00000000 00000000
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.471102] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] ch 4 [0x000f94c000 compiz[2135]] subc 3 class 0x8297 mthd 0x15e0 data 0x00000000
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.471119] nouveau E[     PFB][0000:01:00.0] trapped read at 0x002093a000 on channel 0x0000f94c [compiz[2135]] PGRAPH/VFETCH/00 reason: DMAOBJ_LIMIT
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.471140] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] TRAP_VFETCH FAULT
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.471151] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] TRAP_VFETCH 00f00000 0000fe0c 00000000 00000000
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.471160] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] ch 4 [0x000f94c000 compiz[2135]] subc 3 class 0x8297 mthd 0x0dc8 data 0x00000000
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.471320] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] TRAP_VFETCH FAULT
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.471332] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] TRAP_VFETCH 00f00000 0000fe0c 00000000 00000000
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.471340] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] ch 4 [0x000f94c000 compiz[2135]] subc 3 class 0x8297 mthd 0x1b0c data 0x1000f010
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.471355] nouveau E[     PFB][0000:01:00.0] trapped read at 0x00204b6180 on channel 0x0000f94c [compiz[2135]] PGRAPH/VFETCH/00 reason: DMAOBJ_LIMIT
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.487181] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] TRAP_VFETCH FAULT
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.487202] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] TRAP_VFETCH 00f00000 0000fe0c 00000000 00000000
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.487215] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] ch 4 [0x000f94c000 compiz[2135]] subc 3 class 0x8297 mthd 0x15e0 data 0x00000000
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.487233] nouveau E[     PFB][0000:01:00.0] trapped read at 0x002093a000 on channel 0x0000f94c [compiz[2135]] PGRAPH/VFETCH/00 reason: DMAOBJ_LIMIT
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.487264] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] TRAP_VFETCH FAULT
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.487275] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] TRAP_VFETCH 00f00000 0000fe0c 00000000 00000000
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.487280] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] ch 4 [0x000f94c000 compiz[2135]] subc 3 class 0x8297 mthd 0x0dc8 data 0x00000000
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.487444] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] TRAP_VFETCH FAULT
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.487456] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] TRAP_VFETCH 00f00000 0000fe0c 00000000 00000000
Nov 17 21:18:16 pavel-desktop kernel: [  275.487465] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're using *Compiz Fusion* and the errors are associated with it. Have you tried disabling or uninstalling it to see whether there is any improvement in system stability?

Answer (score 1):

[Sadly, it looks like this is a bug in Nouveau.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/461936/whole-system-freezes-even-tty-does-not-work.)  You can try updating your kernel or using NVIDIA's proprietary drivers instead.